# C++ Scope of Static Variable In a Static Member Function

Tags: c++, static

I have a simple object which does some parsing. Inside, there is a parse function, containing a static variable that is used to limit number of error messages to print to the user:

```
struct CMYParsePrimitive {
    static bool Parse(const std::string &s_line)
    {
        // do the parsing

        static bool b_warned = false;
        if(!b_warned) {
            b_warned = true;
            std::cerr << "error: token XYZ is deprecated" << std::endl;
        }
        // print a warning about using this token (only once)

        return true;
    }
};
```

Now these parse primitives are passed in a typelist to a parser specialization. There is some other interface which tells parser which token types should be parsed using which parse primitives.

My issue is that the warning should be displayed up to once per application run. But in my case, it is sometimes displayed multiple times, seems to be per parser instance rather than application instance.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008, I imagine this might be some bug or a deviation from the standard? Does anyone have any idea as to why this happens?

Comment: Are you using multiple threads?

Comment: Maybe the shown class is not the real code, and the real class is a template. Maybe you have a threading issue. Who knows. Post a **minimal but complete** example, please.

Comment: Are you sure your code isn't setting `b_warned` back to `false` somewhere down the line?

Comment: If the warning above prints multiple times you have a threading issue or the implementation is buggy: local `static` variables exist once in a program.

Comment: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself." -- Sorry.

Comment: It's working perfectly for me. can you please add the code that causes the problem

Comment: Does this code exist in a library which is being linked into multiple DLLs? In that case each DLL will have its own copy of the static data.

Comment: VS2008 has its fair share of bugs, but this one is yours.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf thanks, a perfect guess. Indeed, I missed noticing that the function itself is a template function. Duh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I failed to notice that the function is also a template. My bad. It is instantiated twice in the code with different parameters - hence the warning is sometimes printed twice. The real code looks more like this:

```
struct CMYParsePrimitive {
    template <class CSink>
    static bool Parse(const std::string &s_line, CSink &sink)
    {
        // do the parsing, results passed down to "sink"

        static bool b_warned = false;
        if(!b_warned) {
            b_warned = true;
            std::cerr << "error: token XYZ is deprecated" << std::endl;
        }
        // print a warning about using this token (only once)

        return true;
    }
};
```

So then there are e.g. `CMYParsePrimitive::Parse<PreviewParser>::b_warned`, which can print the warning once when used by `PreviewParser`, and then also `CMYParsePrimitive::Parse<Parser>::b_warned` which can print the warning when used by `Parser`.